# What Power Query for combinations between Excel tables?

Tags: excel, combinations, powerquery

Although it's pretty straightforward in SQL, I can't get the Power Query M code required to get all combinations between association tables in Excel. Here are my (fictitious) tables and data:

Color:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| #FF0000 | Red |
| #00FF00 | Green |
| #0000FF | Blue |

Object:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Obj001 | Sofa |
| Obj002 | Chair |

Paint:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Pnt001 | Myrtle |
| Pnt002 | Sunset |

ColorInObject (first association):

| ObjectID | ColorID |
| --- | --- |
| Obj001 | #FF0000 |
| Obj001 | #00FF00 |
| Obj002 | #FF0000 |
| Obj002 | #0000FF |

ColorInPaint (second association):

| PaintID | ColorID |
| --- | --- |
| Pnt001 | #FF0000 |
| Pnt001 | #0000FF |
| Pnt002 | #00FF00 |
| Pnt002 | #0000FF |

With the simple following SQL query:

```
SELECT Object.Name, Paint.Name, Color.Name
FROM Object, Paint, Color, ColorInObject, ColorInPaint
WHERE ColorInObject.ColorID = Color.ID AND ColorInObject.ObjectID = Object.ID
AND ColorInPaint.ColorID = Color.ID AND ColorInPaint.PaintID = Paint.ID
AND ColorInObject.ColorID = ColorInPaint.ColorID
```

I get the following expected result of all possible combinations between objects and paints through colors:

| Object.Name | Paint.Name | Color.Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sofa | Myrtle | Red |
| Chair | Myrtle | Red |
| Sofa | Sunset | Green |
| Chair | Myrtle | Blue |
| Chair | Sunset | Blue |

How can I get the same result in Excel with Power Query? What would be the required Power Query M code?

Many thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, Power Query works on the idea of joining just two tables at a time so you need to take a series of steps.

Using just the GUI to merge and expand columns, you can get the final result with M code that looks like this:

```
let
    Source = ColorInObject,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"ColorID"}, ColorInPaint, {"ColorID"}, "ColorInPaint", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded ColorInPaint" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "ColorInPaint", {"PaintID"}, {"PaintID"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded ColorInPaint", {"ObjectID"}, Object, {"ID"}, "Object", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Object" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Object", {"Name"}, {"Object.Name"}),
    #"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Object", {"ColorID"}, Color, {"ID"}, "Color", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Color" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "Color", {"Name"}, {"Color.Name"}),
    #"Merged Queries3" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Color", {"PaintID"}, Paint, {"ID"}, "Paint", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Paint" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries3", "Paint", {"Name"}, {"Paint.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Paint",{"Object.Name", "Color.Name", "Paint.Name"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

You can cut down on some of the verbosity if you tinker with the M by hand:

```
let
    JoinTables =
        Table.NestedJoin(
            Table.NestedJoin(
                Table.NestedJoin(
                    Table.Join(
                        ColorInPaint, "ColorID",
                        ColorInObject, "ColorID"
                    ), "ObjectID",
                    Object, "ID", "Object"
                ), "PaintID",
                Paint, "ID", "Paint"
            ), "ColorID",
            Color, "ID", "Color"
        ),
    Expand =
        Table.ExpandTableColumn(
            Table.ExpandTableColumn(
                Table.ExpandTableColumn(
                    JoinTables, "Object", {"Name"}, {"Object.Name"}
                ), "Paint", {"Name"}, {"Paint.Name"}
            ), "Color", {"Name"}, {"Color.Name"}
        )
in
    Table.SelectColumns(Expand,{"Object.Name", "Paint.Name", "Color.Name"})
```

Comment: Thank you Alexis.

This looks good, but I'm getting the following error:
An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: The name 'ColorInPaint' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

I'm a complete newbie in Power Query so I'm probably missing something at a basic level. The table names are those in my Excel workbook, might they not be recognized by Power Query? If so, what additional operations/code should I do?

Thank you again.

Comment: You need to make sure you've loaded all the tables you've mentioned into the query editor, otherwise it doesn't know what you're referring to.

Comment: I finally found it by myself. Works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want all combinations of rows from two tables

Load first table into powerquery by highlighting range and using Data .. From Table/Range [x] my table has headers

Add Column .. custom Column ... column name **Custom** and formula **=1**

File Close and load

Load Second table into powerquery by highlighting range and using Data .. From Table/Range [x] my table has headers

Add Column .. custom Column ... column name **Custom** and formula **=1**

Home .. Merge Queries ... click on Custom on both top and bottom and change join kind to **full outer**.  hit OK

Click the >><< arrows atop the new column and expand